# Drop rows depending of different criterias where there are also nulls and NA's

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, automation

I have a df that contains multiple columns but I want to filter for an automation.

Columns are called (X and Y) but I want to select the by position in the dataset not the name of the column.Those columns have values from 0 to 100 and NA's. ( I cannot delete row's with NA's because it has important information)
I want to make a filter to drop the columns where:

X >= 96.5 and Y >96 for example.

The problem is that I've got the same error all the time:

*TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'float'*

I've been looking in StackOverflow but can't find the solution.

I tried

```
df.drop(df[(df.columns[9] > 96.5) & (df.columns[12] > 96.5)].index)
```

In that case df.columns[9] is X and df.columns[12] is Y.

Any suggestions/ideas??
Thank you in advance!

Comment: looks like you have a MultiIndex column rather. need to fix first that

Comment: I already reset_index() of the df

Comment: *column* rather than index

Comment: Can you help me with that??

Comment: you can start with `print(df.columns)`; if applicable, you can share here. it will tell you how the columns really are

Comment: 'index',       'warehouse_id',     'warehouse_type',
                  'country',          ('X', 34),       ('W', 34),
       ('Z', 34),          ('X', 35),       ('W', 35),
       ('Z', 35),          ('X', 36),       ('W', 36),
       ('Z', 36),          ('X', 37),       ('W', 37),
       ('Z', 37),             'W_total',   'perc_per_country',
           ('wk_cpu', 33.0),     ('wk_cpu', 34.0),     ('wk_cpu', 35.0),
           ('wk_cpu', 36.0)],
      dtype='object')

Comment: okay so it is not MultiIndex column but some column names are tuples :\ And there's no "Y" in there? Anyway, you can do this: `df[~((df[("X", 36)] > 96.5) | (df[("X", 37)] > 96.5))].copy()` -- this will give you a new dataframe where the rows for which X,36 values OR X,37 values are greater than 96.5 are *gone*. Your mistake was doing `("X", 36) > 96.5` kind of thing; after having a column name, you should index into the dataframe, and then compare.

Comment: Yeah! Thank you but if  I want to select the column by position like df.columns[3], how should I do it?

Comment: that's how you do it! like `df[df.columns[3]]` instead of `df[("X", 34)]`. All you need is to index the dataframe with what you choose. Because `df.columns[3]` is literally the *name* of the 3rd column; not the whole column values!

Comment: So finally my expression should be : `dea_cpu.drop(dea_cpu[dea_cpu.columns[9]] > 96.5 & dea_cpu[dea_cpu.columns[12]] > 96.5.index) `???

Comment: almost but not quite. first, you need parantheses around conditions. second, since the thing inside the drop returns a Boolean series (True/False)s, we don't use `drop` but instead directly index the dataframe with it. If there is True, that row is kept; else, dropped.

Comment: So `dea_cpu[~((dea_cpu[dea_cpu.columns[9]] > 96.5) & (dea_cpu[dea_cpu.columns[12]] > 96.5))].copy()`

Comment: I negated the entire condition with `~`; because you wanted to drop where those conditions were True; so with `~`, True -> False and False ->True conversion, i.e., negation happens. So we index the frame with it and keep them. The `.copy()` at the end is so that if you do further manipulations on the result, you won't get SettingWithCopyWarning; it guarantees it's a copy.

Comment: Thakn you so much!!! Love u :D